# Problem when installing Ruby using RVM

Tags: ruby, rvm

I am having a hard time trying to reinstall Ruby (1.9.2-p136) on my ubuntu machine, using RVM.

Basically I just do:

```
rvm install 1.9.2-p136
```

And during the *Compiling* step, it fails with the following error message:

> (NoMethodError) undefined method
>   `set_encoding' for RDoc::Parser:Class

I tried to look for this on Stackoverflow and Google but it didn't help!

Any idea?

Thanks!

EDIT:
To be clear, I am not using Ubuntu but Linux Mint 9 which is based on Ubuntu 10.04.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, oddly enough, RDoc was rev'd last week to a new version. So, I suspect you're running into a snag with it, maybe Ruby 1.9.2-p136, and maybe RVM.

I'd recommend contacting the author of RVM; You can email him at the address that appears when you do `rvm -v`. Include the output of `rvm info`.

I'll do an install to a VM on my machine here and see how it goes. I have the same Ruby version, but it's been in place since it came out, so when RDoc updated there was an existing Ruby. I have the most recent Mint, which I assume is 9, based on Ubuntu 10 I think it said.

---

EDIT:

I just built a Mint 10 VM, then installed rvm, then installed 1.8.7-p330 and 1.9.2-p136. Neither had any problems.

One thing I didn't do, that Wayne Seguin told me is important, is to `rvm notes` after installing it, before installing Ruby. That will display any OS-specific things needed. For instance, on Mint 10 it says:

> dependencies:
>
> For RVM
>
> rvm: bash curl git
>
> For Ruby (MRI & ree)  you should install the following OS dependencies:
>
> ruby: /usr/bin/aptitude install build-essential bison openssl libreadline6 libreadline6-dev curl git-core zlib1g zlib1g-dev libssl-dev libyaml-dev libsqlite3-0 libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 libxml2-dev libxslt-dev autoconf libc6-dev

---

EDIT:

An additional thing you might run into is a zlib warning when installing gems, which is handled on the RVM site in [Zlib](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/packages/zlib/)

Comment: Thanks for sharing this information. I'll just email him then and see what's going on!

Comment: Ruby installed! Thank you for your help!

Comment: Glad it helped. Remember to do `rvm get head; rvm reload` weekly or monthly to pull in the latest fixes/updates.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your problem is, but I've had to install rails to a couple of ubuntu machines and it was a nightmare compiling everything. I recently found:

http://thechangelog.com/post/2857400260/railsready-setup-script-to-get-ruby-and-rails-running

This is the only way I would install rails in ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks, it looks good! Unfortunately it doesn't like the fact that I am using Linux Mint: Rails Ready currently only supports Ubuntu and CentOS, despite the fact that Linus Mint is actually built from Ubuntu!

Comment: I've never had a problem installing Rails on any machine once I have all the dependencies for Ruby taken care of.